# [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead when trying to boot from bootable USB with ubuntu server

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, acpi, tpm

I get these errors. I disabled Secure Boot in BIOS but still same. I'm installing Ubuntu Server into Dell Precision Tower 3640. Refer to photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNJS4.jpg).

```
[O.321005] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [WST1] (00000000ccd82500) [GenericSerialBus](20190816/evregion-129)
[T0.321005] ACPI Error: Region GenericSerialBus (ID=9) has no handler (20190816/exfldio-261)
[0.321005] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO. I2CO.PAS1 due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190816/psparse-529)
[0.321005] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE.L42 due to previous error (AE_NOT _EXIST) (20190816/psparse-529)
[0.321005] ACPI Error: AE _NOT _EXIST, while evaluating GPE method [_L42] (20190816/eugpe-511)
[0.6901531 tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: IPM interrupt not working, polling instead
```

Comment: If you don't need it then just disable TPM.

Comment: The TPM error cleared, but others remaining. And I still can't boot into the installer. Trying to flash the USB drive once again.

Comment: Yes, good move. You should also consider updating UEFI if there's an update available.

Comment: Found out that the error is negligible and doesn’t affect the boot process. It’s a graphic issue which causes the screen to hang there. Tried it on my other computer just now, its working fine.

Comment: Also look at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213323.

Comment: In Whitley-based systems (Lenovo): https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht512219-the-message-firmware-bug-tpm-interrupt-not-working-polling-instead-is-reported-when-executing-dmesg-on-whitley-based-systems-lenovo-thinksystem